# 400 Bad request response on any application/json request

Tags: php, json, laravel

Laravel server returns Bad Request response on any request with content-type application/json. Everything else works fine, local version works fine, but same files deployed doesn't.

Even when I type wrong uri, same message appears, regardless of content.

Of course, json is properly formatted, as I stated, local version works just fine, and when I send a request using regular post fields (instead of application/json) it also works.

UPDATE:
server log shows problem with Modsecurity, server doesn't know how to handle JSON. I still don't know what to do...

Comment: Have you checked the URI , that was sent by your application/json request  ?

Comment: URI is ok, as I said, when Content-type is changed, and I send data via post fields, everything works fine, with the same URI

Comment: disable mod_security, disable apache, use nginx :D or disable the rule or whitelist application/json. simply google for mod_security json. rule sstart with `SecRule` in the configs.